# Forcing a popup to the foreground

Tags: javascript, vbscript, dom-events

I'm wondering if people can help me or if my way of thinking wont work. I am not a coder so I don't get to involved in writing, just learn as I go.

I have web page one that refreshes every 5 mins. This page launches a popup.

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function MM_openBrWindow(theURL,winName,features) { //v2.0
  window.open(theURL,winName,features);
}
//-->
</script>
</head>
<body  önload="MM_openBrWindow('call_notice.html','CallWaiting','width=200,height=200')">"
```

Now if this page is currently in the background the popup also appears in the background. I need this page to come to the foreground to notify the user that the pages has refreshed. Popup has the following code:

```
<i>
<body onblur="self.focus()"  önload="self.focus()">
<p align="center" class="style1">You have a call. </p>
<p align="center" class="style1">Please close this window to continue.</p>
<p align="center" class="style1"> </p>
<form method="post">
  <div align="center">
    <input type="button" value="Continue" 
 ö'nclick="window.close()">
</div>
</form> 
</i>
```

I have tried `set.focus` seen some `setforegroundwindow`, but can't get it to work. Seen z-order but that doesn't make sens to me.

Has any one got any ideas on how I can do it, or has something that monitors windows titles and executes something?

Any help would be great. I don't write from scratch but take bits here and there just to let you now what type of person you are dealing with.

Basically I want the popup to popup in front of all windows when the web pages at the back (which could 4 programs back) refreshes. Not sure how to paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

yourpopupwindow.focus() should work. That's in javascript, have no idea about vbsript.

Like so:

```
        function win_open(oid) {
       yourpopupwindow = window.open('yoururl', 'popupwin',             'menubar=no,history=no,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,width=600,height=300');
{yourpopupwindow.focus()}
       }
```

Then on refresh you can either close popup if it's open and open new one and focus on it, or just focus on existing one.

Comment: So after reading updated question - just add winName.focus(); to the end of your MM_openBrWindow function